# IOS. Parsing and evaluating logical and math expressions

Tags: ios, parsing, expression

I'm looking for a library for parsing and evaluating logical and math expressions from String. The main features what i need:

- Check expression's type(logical or math )
- Parsing and evaluating math expressions. Ex: "3*(2+1)"
- Parsing and evaluating logical expressions. Ex: "(2+1 == 0) || (5 >= 10)"
- Must be work also with Strings. Ex: " ('B' != 'A') && ('k' != 'K') "

I found [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) library, but it сan't compare Strings.

Comment: Instead, post it as an *answer* post to your own question and if a better answer doesn't come along in two days you'll be permitted to accept the answer.  It will be quicker for people to find in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation some time I decided to use [CoreParse](https://github.com/beelsebob/CoreParse) library. This library is using BNF language for describe grammars. In my case the grammar has next form:

```
var expressionGrammar = "Expression     ::= exprb@<BoolExpression> | exprm@<MathExpression> | exprs@<StringExpression>;\n" +
    "MathExpression ::= term@<MathTerm>   | expr@<MathExpression> op@<AddOp> term@<MathTerm>;\n" +
    "MathTerm       ::= fact@<MathFactor> | fact@<MathFactor>     op@<MulOp> term@<MathTerm>;\n" +
    "MathFactor     ::= num@'Number'  | '(' expr@<MathExpression> ')';\n" +
    "MulOp      ::= '*' | '/';\n" +
    "AddOp      ::= '+' | '-';\n" +

    "StringExpression   ::= fact@<StringFactor> | expr@<StringExpression> op@<AddOp> fact@<StringFactor>;\n" +
    "StringFactor       ::= str@'String' | '(' expr@<StringExpression> ')';\n" +

    "BoolExpression ::= term@<BoolTerm> |   term@<BoolTerm> op@<LogicOp> expr@<BoolExpression>;\n" +
    "BoolTerm   ::= fact@<BoolFactor>   |   fact@<BoolFactor> op@<CompareOp> term@<BoolTerm>;\n" +
    "BoolFactor ::= value@<LogicValue>  | '(' expr@<BoolExpression> ')' | factm1@<MathFactor> op@<CompareOp> factm2@<MathFactor>    | facts1@<StringFactor> op@<CompareOp> facts2@<StringFactor>;\n" +
    "CompareOp  ::= '<' | '>' | '>=' | '<=' | '==' | '!=';\n" +
    "LogicOp    ::= '&&' | '||';\n" +
    "LogicValue ::= val@'true' | val@'false';\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

DDMathParser can absolutely compare strings. You'd enable the "interprets strings as variables" options and then add a custom variable resolver to compare a variable expression to another variable expression and return the true/false result.

I will come back later and show how this is possible.